# .htaccess alias, but not redirect

Tags: .htaccess, alias, concrete5

I have a CMS (Concrete5) and I have switched on "nice urls"...

for example, 
`http:/ /www.mydomain.at/test/` is `http:/ /www.mydomain.at/index.php?cid=1` in dir /var/www/user1/www.mydomain.at/

now i want to use a mobile-template

```
http:/ /mobile.mydomain.at/test/mobile-version/ in dir /var/www/user1/mobile.mydomain.at/
```

that should be an alias of `http:/ /www.mydomain.at/test/mobile-version/`

i dont want a redirect, it should be an alias...

please help - thx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enable `Mod_Proxy` than add these lines to `.htaccess` in Mobile-version folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mobile\.mydomain\.at$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+)$ http://www.mydomain.at/$1 [L,P]
```